# main() appears to not be called on QtCore inclusion

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have the following main.cpp file:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  *(int*)(NULL) = 5;
  delete (void*)(4);
  throw int(0);
  std::abort();
}
```

This, of course, results in a crash. Add the following magic line to the top of the header file:

```
#include <QtCore>
```

And no matter what abuse I put into main(), the program doesn't crash. Conclusion: main isn't being called.

Why..?

**My CMake file:**

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC on)

file(GLOB_RECURSE source_files *.cpp *.c)

add_executable(myexec ${source_files})
qt5_use_modules(myexec Widgets)
```

CMake 2.8.10 (MSVS 11 Win64), Qt 5.0.2

Comment: Can you try adding just "#include <QApplication>" and not QtCore ?

Comment: @VaibhavDesai Results in the same outcome.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai I take that back. That was an outdated executable. Just `#include`ing the QApplication header results in a crash (main being called). However, adding the following two lines results `main()` not being called: `QApplication app(argc,argv);return app.exec();`. Presumably, there's something fishy happening with the linking process, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai So, while you didn't really 'add to the post', I still upvoted your comment because it pushed me in the direction to find the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It *was* a problem with the linker.

I ran Dependency Walker on the executable and found that the Qt5Widgets.dll file wasn't being found by the shell I was running it from. This apparently caused silent linker errors. Problem was fixed upon updating environment variables.

Moral of the story: **ALWAYS KEEP YOUR ENVIRONMENT CLEAN, TIDY, AND UP TO DATE**. Windows *isn't* nice like Linux and will not tell you jack if a DLL can't be found. <_<